# Convert string ">0" to python > 0

Tags: python

I read the conditions ">0", "<60", etc., from a xml file. What is the best way to convert them to python language to compare? The sample code is what I want to do:

```
    if str == ">0":
        if x > 0:
            print "yes"
        else:
            print "no"
    elif str == "<60":
        if x < 60:
            print "yes"
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are very confident that the data in the XML file is properly sanitized, then you could use [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval).

```
'yes' if eval(str(x) + op) else 'no'
```

Although this solution is much simpler than the other answers, it is also probably slower (however I have not tested this).

Answer (score 8):

I would use [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) and [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html).

```
from operator import lt, gt
import re

operators = {
    ">": gt,
    "<": lt,
}

string = ">60"
x = 3

op, n = re.findall(r'([><])(\d+)', string)[0]

print(operators[op](x, int(n)))
```

Depending on your string, the regex can be modified.

Comment: Beat me to it, was just about to post the same basic answer. I'd have skipped the regex for the simple case, though I'll admit to it being kinda hackish either way; `digits = somestr.lstrip('><=')`, `op = somestr[:-len(digits)]`, `n = int(digits)`. I was also going to include `'>=': operator.ge` and `'<=': operator.le` in the `dict` for inequality completeness.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I thought to using regex because I find it more flexible in the case OP's strings become more complicated in the future. But using `lstrip()` is a good way he should consider.

Comment: Yeah, regex is fine in this case (it's on the borderline between "use simple string ops" and "use regex", and it's only my philosophical objection to regex overuse causing me to err on the side of "no regex"). I was just commenting for alternatives (I didn't want to post a mostly redundant answer when yours is good just to include that tiny tweak).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe simply use slice?

```
string = "<60"
x = 3

op = string[0]
number = int(string[1:].strip())

if op == '>':
    print 'yes' if x > number else 'no'
else:
    print 'yes' if x < number else 'no'
```

Output:

```
yes
```